# Ninject bind by convention using BindToFactory to a factory interface with class T

Tags: ninject, factory, ninject-extensions

I want to replace this code:

```
Kernel.Bind<ITaskFactory<AlertTask>>().ToFactory();
Kernel.Bind<ITaskFactory<PopupTask>>().ToFactory();
```

with something like this:

```
Kernel.Bind(scanner => scanner.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses()
   .EndingWith("Task").MAGICGOESHERE().BindToFactory()
```

I tried to create a IBindingGenerator, but stranded when trying to get ITaskFactory<T> from T.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
kernel.Bind(scanner => scanner
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllInterfaces()
    .EndingWith("Factory")
    .BindToFactory());

kernel.Bind(scanner => scanner
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .EndingWith("Task"));

var f = kernel.Get<ITaskFactory>();
var task1 = f.CreateTask<AlertTask>();
var task2 = f.CreateTask<PopupTask>();

public class AlertTask {}
public class PopupTask { }
public interface ITaskFactory
{
    T CreateTask<T>();
}
```

Comment: Easy and elegant solution. Thank you. The generic ITaskFactory cleaned up a lot of other code to. The ITaskFactory can also have function of the form T CreateTask<T>(TaskInformation info);